# How to get vim key-bindings for GVim in Windows?

Tags: windows, vim, gvim, key-binding

GVim for Windows overwrites a lot of useful vim commands, such as ctrl+A and ctrl+Y. Is there a way to get these commands back without writing a remap for each and every command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
:behave mswin
```

And, if that works for you, look at this [other answer at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688934/how-to-config-the-gvim-as-a-ide-for-c-c-java-in-windows/689005#689005).

Also see, [Why does < C-a> (CTRL+A) not work under gvim on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/289681/70482)?

Comment: `:behave mswin` does not solve the problem (and seems to be supposed to do the opposite). Your first link doesn't seem to cover my issue. The second does; I fixed `_vimrc` according to it, and it works fine now.